# PHP - Extract image colors with ColorThief

Tags: php, colors, extract

I found an class on GitHub to extract image colors with php. first i did create a php file and added these lines in to the file:

```
require_once 'ColorThief.php';

$sourceImage = '1.jpg';

use ColorThief\ColorThief;
$palette = ColorThief::getPalette($sourceImage, 8);
```

but the thing is i got this error message and i do not know how to fix it:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ColorThief\Image\ImageLoader' not found in C:\UwAmp\www\ColorThief\ColorThief.php on line 182
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  133416  {main}( )   ...\show.php:0
2   0.0038  198232  ColorThief\ColorThief::getPalette( )    ...\show.php:9
3   0.0038  198440  ColorThief\ColorThief::loadImage( ) ...\ColorThief.php:140
```

do you guys know how i can use this class?
GitHub Page:

https://github.com/ksubileau/color-thief-php

Comment: Did you installed ColorThief with composer withour errors?

Comment: without composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Color Thief with Composer, it's standard for using 3rd party libraries in your projects.

1. Install Composer
2. Check one of these libraries installed (gd or imagick) via phpinfo for example

> gd (php_gd2.dll) - http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php
>
> imagick (php_imagick.dll) - http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

3. Choose you project folder and run

> composer require ksubileau/color-thief-php

4. Use autoload for including color-thief

> require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';